# On a web performance test, can I specify multiple expected response pages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, coded-ui-tests

When dealing with a coded web performance test (in C#), is it possible to tell the web test to expect multiple valid response pages? We have certain criteria that happen on login, and the user may be taken to a few different pages depending on some flags, so expecting a single response URL isn't really possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use the extract rules to extract something from each page you could get redirected to?

Here you can find some guidance of how to set things up:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/901/web-performance-test-using-visual-studio-part-i

or if this doesn't work for you, you could also code your custom validation rule:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182556.aspx

Comment: I can't use an extract rule because the name of the page isn't known on the page before it. Extraction rules are only used to extract information from previous responses. And I don't want to use a custom validation rule because this would defeat the purpose of using the global Response URL Validator that is applied to every page, which I would prefer to use since it saves time/code.

Comment: Ok, in this case my best guess would be to create a custom variant of the ResponseURLValidator and have a collection of URLs passed in somehow to validate against...
Example can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogeorge/archive/2011/06/01/visual-studio-webtest-validation-rules-built-in-response-url-rule-is-case-sensitive.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On a Coded UI test of a web page that could return either of two quite different pages I wrote the following code. It worked fine for that test, there are several possible tidy ups that I would investigate if I needed similar again. So please consider this as a starting point.

The basic idea is to see check the current web page for text identifying which of the expected pages is currently shown. If found then deal with that page. If not found then pause for a short time to allow the page to load, then look again. Added in a time out in case an expected page never appears.

```
public void LookForResultPages()
{
    Int32 maxMilliSecondsToWait = 3 * 60 * 1000;
    bool processedPage = false;

    do
    {
        if ( CountProperties("InnerText", "Some text on most common page") > 0 )
        {
            ... process that page;
            processedPage = true;
        }
        else if ( CountProperties("InnerText", "Some text on another page") > 0 )
        {
            ... process that page;
            processedPage = true;
        }
        else
        {
            const Int32 pauseTime = 500;
            Playback.Wait(pauseTime); // In milliseconds
            maxMilliSecondsToWait -= pauseTime;
        }
    } while ( maxMilliSecondsToWait > 0 && !processedPage );

    if ( !processedPage )
    {
        ... handle timeout;
    }
}

public int CountProperties(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    HtmlControl html = new HtmlControl(this.myBrowser);
    UITestControlCollection htmlcol = new UITestControlCollection();
    html.SearchProperties.Add(propertyName, propertyValue, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
    htmlcol = html.FindMatchingControls();

    return htmlcol.Count;
}
```